# Pyspark - How to assess multicollinearity? VIF equivalent

Tags: python, pyspark

As the title states, I'm trying to find a way to assess multicollinearity in pyspark? Usually, I would use statsmodel's VIF but I don't see an equivalent function within pyspark.

Any recommendations on how I could go about calculating multicollinearity would be much appreciated.

Comment: Take a sample, apply VIF on a sample?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a correlation matrix :

```
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
sc=spark.sparkContext
import numpy as np

seriesX = sc.parallelize([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0])  # a series
# seriesY must have the same number of partitions and cardinality as seriesX
seriesY = sc.parallelize([11.0, 22.0, 33.0, 33.0, 555.0])

# Compute the correlation using Pearson's method. Enter "spearman" for Spearman's method.
# If a method is not specified, Pearson's method will be used by default.
print("Correlation is: " + str(Statistics.corr(seriesX, seriesY, method="pearson")))

data = sc.parallelize(
    [np.array([1.0, 10.0, 100.0]), np.array([2.0, 20.0, 200.0]), np.array([5.0, 33.0, 366.0])]
)  # an RDD of Vectors

# calculate the correlation matrix using Pearson's method. Use "spearman" for Spearman's method.
# If a method is not specified, Pearson's method will be used by default.
print(Statistics.corr(data, method="pearson"))
```

The output looks like:

```
# Correlation is: 0.8500286768773004
                                                                                
# [[1.         0.97888347 0.99038957]
# [0.97888347 1.         0.99774832]
# [0.99038957 0.99774832 1.        ]]
```

Docs : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-statistics.html